# How to use ngFor loop to select third value list based on first two selected values

Tags: arrays, json, angular, angular6, angular7

I have a form with four select fields. Respectively Branch, semester, and subject. I want to show the subject option list according to the selected branch and semester. Which type of JSON or Array should I create? And how to loop through that using *ngFor in angular 7.

Answer (score 0):

Track your changes for each field OnInit in your FormControl via subscription to valueChanges.

```
branch = ['Computer', 'Civil', 'Electronics','Mechanical' ];
semester = ['1st', '2nd', '3rd','4th','5th','6th', '7th', '8th'];
formGroup: FormGroup;
subjectOptions: [] = [];
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

ngOnInit(): void {
  // I like to use Formbuilder b/c the syntax is less verbose.
  this.formGroup = this.fb.group({
    branch: '',
    semester: '',
    subject: '',
  });

  this.formGroup.valueChanges.subscribe(newGroupValue => {
    // Match criteria
    if (newGroupValue.branch === 'Computer' && newGroupValue.semester === '3rd') {
      // However you want to generate a new array of options to display in select
      this.subjectOptions = [
       'C++','Data Structure','DE'
      ];
    }
  }
});
```

Then loop over new select options.

You can make the array of options into an object that has properties for name and value. Then use one-way property binding for them.

```
<div [formGroup]="formGroup">
  // Rest of the dropdowns above w/ corresponding formControlName
  <select formControlName="subject">
     <option *ngFor="let option of subjectOptions" [name]="option.name" [value]="option.value"></option>
  </selct>
</div>
```

If you don't want to do a lot of if elses, you can set up your options to look something like this.

```
const branches = {
    computer: {
        name: 'Computer',
        semesters: {
            third: {
                name: '3rd',
                subjects: {
                    c: {
                        name: 'C++'
                    },
                    'data-structure': {
                        name: 'Data Structure'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can use a Map object... etc... As long as it's accessible by key.

Then on valueChange of your form, inside the subscription callback:

```
this.formGroup.valueChanges.subscribe(newGroupValue => {
   if (newGroupValue.branch && newGroupValue.semester) {
      this.subjectOptions = branches[newGroupValue.branch].semesters[newGroupValue.semester].subjects;
   }
}
```

From there, you can use the KeyValuePipe to iterate through this object's levels.

Comment: Is there any way to use *ngFor="let sub of branch.sem" where we can change "branch"and"sub" value dynamically means "branch.sem" value to get json object of subjects

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, for each branch, you have children nested under a semesters property. Something like this? `branch = { sem: [{subject: [...subjects]}]}` Can you show me your model to clarify?

Comment: I have two simple arrays: branch = ['Computer', 'Civil', 'Electronics','Mechanical' ];
and semesters = ['1st', '2nd', '3rd','4th','5th','6th', '7th', '8th']; so I can easily loop through that using *ngFor. But now based on both of this selection I want to get options for the third select field which show subjects according to selected branch and sem. For example: if I select computer and 3rd sem then the third field should show subject options C++,DataStructure,DE.

Comment: I updated the above code a little to match your last comment. It seems that there could be a LOT of combinations, so I would recommend making a complex object nesting them and then using the KeyValuePipe within *ngFor to map through that object.
(https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe)

Comment: Then I'll have to use lots of else if conditions. Because I have 4 branches with 8 semesters each. About 32. :)

Comment: Updated so you don't have to use if else's.